# C - How to run a thread for a couple seconds and then continue with a second thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm working on my program where I want thread 1 to run for 2.1 seconds, after 2.1 seconds I want thread 2 to run for 3.4 seconds and then it needs to switch back to thread 1. I've managed to make both threads run, but without the given time. It is required that I use 2 threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main() {

    void* taskOne();
    void* taskTwo();

    pthread_attr_t tattr;
    pthread_attr_init(&tattr);

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    double seconds1 = 2.1;
    double seconds2 = 3.4;


    pthread_create(&thread1, &tattr, taskOne, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, &tattr, taskTwo, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void* taskOne() {
    int i, j, m, n;
    while (1) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
                printf("thread: 1 periodnumber: %i\n", j);
                for (m = 0; m <= 1250; m++)
                    for (n = 0; n <= 250000; n++);


            }
        }
    }
}

void* taskTwo() {
    int i, j, m, n;
    while (1) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
                printf("thread: 2 periodnumber: %i\n", j);
                for (m = 0; m <= 2750; m++)
                    for (n = 0; n <= 250000; n++);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try very hard to redesign your app to not do this.

Comment: You say that you are _required_ to use two threads. Is that because this is a homework problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your thread sleep for whatever time you want by calling the sleep() function, however this is a "sleep *for* x seconds" not "sleep *after* x seconds".

The only way I can think of to implement this would be with a timer running outside your threads to put them to pause() them for the desired times then send a non-kill signal to wake it up when you want it again.

sleep(n) would work, but only handles integers.

Also, there aren't any guarantees that your thread won't be busy with blocking I/O when you try to pause/sleep it, so if it's *really* important that this actually happen exactly as you want, you'll need to do some work to prevent blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Let me re-phrase your question: You want your program to do one thing for 2.1 seconds, then you want it to stop doing that thing, and do some other thing for 3.4 seconds, and then you want it to go back to doing the first thing.

You don't need multiple threads for that. All you need is a way for your two functions to [look at the clock](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).

```
#include <time.h>

do_thing_1(double for_how_long) {
    struct timespec start_time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start_time);
    while (elapsed_time_since(&start_time) < for_how_long) {
        ...
    }
}

do_thing_2(double for_how_long) {
    struct timespec start_time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start_time);
    while (elapsed_time_since(&start_time) < for_how_long) {
        ...
    }
}

main(...) {
    do_thing_1(2.1 /*seconds*/);
    do_thing_2(3.4 /*seconds*/);
    do_thing_1(9999999.9);
}
```

Left as an exercisse for the reader:  Implement `elapsed_time_since(...)`

Extra credit: Write a generic `do_thing(function, for_how_long)` function.

Comment: Yes, I want to run Thread 1 for 2.1sec and then Thread 2 for 3.4 sec, and then back to Thread 1 and so on. I want to use two threads, but can't find the way to implement it.

Comment: @Atame, Yes, I hear you say that you _want_ to use two threads. But, I am saying that you don't _need_ to use two threads.  At least, not unless there is some other requirement you haven't told us about.

Comment: @Atame the requirement makes no sense.  Talk to your boss/customer/client/whatever and tell them.

Comment: @MartinJames you missed /professor and they are usually difficult to convice :)

Comment: I agree, this looks like a homework question. It looks like countless others that I see here that may teach students something about _how_ to use threads, but which fill their heads with horribly wrong ideas about _when_ and _why_ to use threads.

Comment: @besmirched  Yes this is a homework question, I'm still learning about threads. I'm just doing what my teacher is asking me to do.

Comment: I did some research and it seems you can use mutexes? Is this true?

Comment: @Atame A [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) would be better than a mutex. The reason is, when other programmers see the word "mutex" or the word "lock", they will assume that it is being used for _mutual exclusion_ (i.e., to prevent different threads from interfering with each other's use of a shared data structure.) When other programmers see "semaphore," they are more likely to expect it to be used for _signalling_ between different threads. If you had a semaphore, one thread could _signal_ it when it's turn was done, and the other thread could _await_ for...

Comment: ...its turn to begin.  I don't know whether there is some ready-made semaphore library that you can use in a plain C program, or whether you will have to implement your own.

Comment: @besmirched Thanks for your answer, I will look into semaphores!